# WinRT - Update Progress Bar

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, progress-bar

I got a problem when doing animation for the `ProgressBar`.

My objective is, **I want the `ProgressBar.Value` update every time it process `CopyAsync` and `CreateFolderAsync`**.

I have 4 components in my xaml file that will be update every time the process done (`CopyAsync` and `CreateFolderAsync`), the `TextBlock` is running fine, it always update every time the process is done. The problem is in the `ProgressBar` it will update the UI in the end of all the process.

I'm using `Dispatcher.RunAsync`, and the update process for `TextBlock` and `ProgressBar` I put in there.

**Please advise, how to update the `ProgressBar` for the code below.**

---

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<TextBlock Text="Files:" FontSize="72" Margin="363,270,834,402"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="Folders:" FontSize="72" Margin="273,411,834,270"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="Files" FontSize="72" Margin="582,270,609,402"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="Folders" FontSize="72" Margin="582,411,588,270"></TextBlock>
<ProgressBar x:Name="FolderBar" Height="25" Margin="10,532,-10,211"></ProgressBar>
<ProgressBar x:Name="FileBar" Height="25" Margin="10,565,-10,178"></ProgressBar>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private async void CopyFolder(string path)
{
    IStorageFolder destination = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    IStorageFolder root = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    if (path.Equals(ROOT) && !await FolderExistAsync(ROOT))
        await destination.CreateFolderAsync(ROOT);

    destination = await destination.GetFolderAsync(path);
    root = await root.GetFolderAsync(path);

    IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> items = await root.GetItemsAsync();

    // For count the total files
    if (path.Equals(ROOT))
        TotalFiles(path);

    foreach (IStorageItem item in items)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(StorageFile))
        {
            IStorageFile presFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
                new Uri("ms-appx:///" + path.Replace("\\", "/") + "/" + item.Name));

            if (!await FileExistAsync(path, item.Name))
            {
                IStorageFile copyFile = await presFile.CopyAsync(destination);
                countFiles++;

                if (copyFile != null)
                {
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () =>
                        {
                            // The update for TextBlock is fine
                            Files.Text = countFiles.ToString();
                            // But for the ProgressBar it will update in the end of process
                            FileBar.Value = countFiles / totalFiles * 100;
                        });
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!await FolderExistAsync(path + "\\" + item.Name))
            {
                StorageFolder createFolder = await destination.CreateFolderAsync(item.Name);
                countFolders++;

                if (createFolder != null)
                {
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () =>
                        {
                            // The update for TextBlock is fine
                            Folders.Text = countFolders.ToString();
                            // But for the ProgressBar it will update in the end of process
                            FolderBar.Value = countFolders / totalFolders * 100;
                        });
                }

            }

            CopyFolder(path + "\\" + item.Name);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should not update the components via setting their property directly through code. I highly recommend to take a look at the mvvm-pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) or mvvm-light (http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`countFiles` and `totalFiles` are both integers, so when you divide one by the other, it performs an integer division; since `totalFiles` is always greater than or equal to `countFiles`, the result is always 0, except at the end where it's 1.

To fix it, you need to cast to `double` before you divide, in order to perform a floating point division:

```
FileBar.Value = (double)countFiles / totalFiles * 100;
```